# Distribution of difference of iid Random Variables

Tags: probability

If X and Y are iid random variables with distribution $F(x)=e^{-e^{-x}}$ and we let $Z=X-Y$ find the distribution function of $F_Z(x)$. I get $F_Z(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ but that doesn't match the answer that the professor gave us. Is what I have correct? I used the standard approach where I integrate over a region the joint density which is just the product of the two densities. Nothing too fancy I did, its just I think my professor got it wrong.

Comment: Can you show us your work? that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
P(Z\leq z)&=P(X\leq z+Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X\leq z+y) f(y)\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(-e^{-(z+y)})\exp(-y-e^{-y})\,\mathrm dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-y-e^{-y}(1+e^{-z}))\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}\exp(-(1+e^{-z})e^{-y})\right]_{-\infty}^\infty\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did

$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}\{Z\leq z\}=\mathbb{P}\{X-Y\leq z\}=\mathbb{P}\{X\leq Y+z\}$. Now if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{}R^2\;|\;x\leq y+z\}$ we get that the above equals $\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy$. Since $X,Y$ are independent we have $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$. And $f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=e^{-e^{-x}}\cdot e^{-x}$. Then $F_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{y+c}e^{-e^{-x}}\cdot e^{-x}e^{-e^{-y}}\cdot e^{-y}dxdy$. I then take out the y's from the inner integral and integrate wrt $x$ and get a function of y then integrate wrt y and get my answer above.